# Using R-substr for assignment

Tags: r

I have the element: MVa.8.199038.R
I only want to extract the number 199038, using R.
However, I want this to be more general. So, I need a code that will read this element from right to left (starting from the dot) and end to the next dot.
This element is part of a data frame.

I tried this: `substr((df$marker), nchar(df$marker) - 2, \.)`, but this does not give output.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with a look ahead using `stringer`. Without more cases from your data it's hard to be sure how general this might be. I've assumed your number can comprise between 1 and 10 digits. To convert to a number wrap the expression in `as.numeric`.

```r
x <- "MVa.8.199038.R"


stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d{1,10}(?=\\.[^0-9].*$)")
#> [1] "199038"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: OK look forward to hearing how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A couple other options:

```r
x <- "MVa.8.199038.R"

#option 1
sub("^.*?(\\d+)\\.R$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "199038"

#option 2
stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=\\.R)")
#> [1] "199038"
```